# how to flatten more than 2 array nested

Tags: kotlin

I'm a newbie at Kotlin. And when I learn about flatten function

> Returns a single list of all elements from all arrays in the given array.

It is description of that.It work in array nested array. But, how about more than 3 array. Like :

```
val testArray = listOf(listOf(1,2,3), listOf(4,3,9, listOf(3,3,6)))
```

Output I want is:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 9, 3, 3, 6]`

So, anyone can help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: If you run ```flatten``` on ```testArray``` you will get the exact output you specify.

Comment: no need to add `[Android][Kotlin]` to your title, tags are sufficient

Comment: @eimmer I try that on play.kotlinlang.org. But what I got just '[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 9, [3, 3, 6]]'
My test here: https://shorturl.ae/Yfbcq

Comment: @a_local_nobody sr about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun List<*>.deepFlatten(): List<*> = this.flatMap { (it as? List<*>)?.deepFlatten() ?: listOf(it) }
```

Comment: Well, seem your solution is shorter and look more kotlin than the other.

Answer (score 1):

This should work with the countless nested arrays.

```kotlin
fun <T> Iterable<T>.enhancedFlatten(): List<T> {
    val result = ArrayList<T>()
    for (element in this) {
        if (element is Iterable<*>) {
            try {
                result.addAll(element.enhancedFlatten() as Collection<T>)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println(e)
            }
        } else {
            result.add(element)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Enes Kayıklık, It's absolutely what I need. Thanks a lot