# merge/union two string sub arrays inside a json array kotlin

Tags: kotlin, merge, union

is there anyway we can merge/union the two sub arrays inside a json array

```
 jsonArray = [["abc","hello","hai"]["true","false","hai"]]

 expected output would be ["abc","hello","hai","true","false"]
```

any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to parse the json?

Comment: @matt - I am recieving this jsonarray from an sdk and I have tried to loop through the jsonarray to store all the strings in an arraylist but It didnt work.

Comment: Use the [union method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/union.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first flatten it and then turn it into a Set to remove duplicates. For example:

```
val jsonArray = listOf(listOf("abc","hello","hai"), listOf("true","false","hai")) // This is the same as [["abc","hello","hai"]["true","false","hai"]]

val flattenedSetOfJsonArray = map.flatten().toSet()

println(flattenedSetOfJsonArray) // prints [abc, hello, hai, true, false]
```

- Edit

If you want to flatten deeply nested lists you can use this helper method ([credits to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72228659/how-to-flatten-more-than-2-array-nested))

```
fun List<*>.deepFlatten(): List<*> = this.flatMap { (it as? List<*>)?.deepFlatten() ?: listOf(it) }
```

Now use this method like this:

```
val jsonArray = listOf(listOf("abc","hello","hai"), listOf("true","false","hai"), listOf(listOf("true", "false", "abc")))
val flattenedSetOfJsonArray = jsonArray.deepFlatten().toSet()

println(flattenedSetOfJsonArray) // prints [abc, hello, hai, true, false]
```

Comment: Thanks again robin, so what if we have more than two sub arrays in the jsonarray that we get dynamically. I mean the hardcoding way may not be the right.please suggest here.

Comment: @Raghu I edited my answer :) please mark as correct if it's sufficient.